Wish to know details of some text found in a book such as the dynasty and style (vernacular/白話 or classical/文言文)
I am linking a PDF of an old Chinese book below on Google Drive.
Any context you can give about the book would be appreciated, such as whether this is modern or old Chinese and what type of work it is.
PDF of Chinese book

Your PDF is the 4th fascicle of Manual of the Mustard Seed Garden (芥子園畫傳, Jieziyuan Huazhuan), at least your PDF has 芥子園畫傳 卷四 on it. You can find the image of your page 12 on wiki as well. According to wiki, the manual has many versions, so I can’t tell how old or which version your PDF actually is.

Manual of the Mustard Seed Garden (芥子園畫傳, Jieziyuan Huazhuan), sometimes known as Jieziyuan Huapu (芥子園畫譜), is a printed manual of Chinese painting compiled during the early-Qing Dynasty.


The first fascicle deals with the general principles of landscape painting, the second the painting of trees, the third that of hills and stones, the fourth that of people and houses, and the fifth comprises the selected works of great landscape painters.

